# How exactly can I define a controller as service using annotations?

Tags: symfony, service, annotations

This seems to be the fastest and simpliest way to use a controller as service, but I am still missing a step because it doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

Controller/service:

```
// Test\TestBundle\Controller\TestController.php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * @Route(service="test_service")
 */
class TestController extends Controller {
  // My actions
}
```

Use :

```
// Test\TestBundle\Controller\UseController.php

// ...
public function useAction() {
  $testService = $this->get('test_service');
}
```

When I do that, I get the error

> You have requested a non-existent service "test_service".

When I check the list of services with `app/console container:debug`, I don't see my newly created service.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might like this bundle, that adds autowiring for controllers: www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2016/03/10/autowired-controllers-as-services-for-lazy-people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Controller as Service in SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#controller-as-service):

> The @Route annotation on a controller class can also be used to assign the controller class to a service so that the controller resolver will instantiate the controller by fetching it from the DI container instead of calling new PostController() itself:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @Route(service="my_post_controller_service")
>  */
> class PostController
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

The `service` attribute in the annotation is just to tell Symfony it should use the specified service, instead of instantiating the controller with the `new` statement. It does not register the service on its own.

Given your controller:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * @Route(service="test_service")
 */
class TestController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
    }
}
```

You need to actually register the controller as a service with the `test_service` id:

```
services:
    test_service:
        class: Test\TestBundle\Controller\TestController
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can inject your dependencies into the constructor by specifying them in the service definition, and you don't need to extend the base `Controller` class.

See [How to define controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and [Controller as Service in SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#controller-as-service).

Comment: Ok, I got it all wrong then. Thanks for the precise and clear answer!

Answer (score 4):

For future folks, if you decide to use controller-as-a-service, you should better inject your services into the controller via the constructor instead of getting them through a service locator. The former is considered to be an antipattern, while the latter allows easy unit testing and is simply more verbose.

So instead of:

```
public function useAction() {
    $testService = $this->get('test_service');
}
```

You should:

```
private $yourService;

public function __construct(YourService $yourService)
{
    $this->yourService = $yourService;
}

public function useAction()
{
    $this->yourService->use(...);
}
```

Don't create shortcuts, write solid, maintainable code.

Comment: This is actually the main reason to make them as services. :D

Answer (score 0):

For [Symfony 3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/service.html), we don't need to register controllers as services because they are already registered as services with the default `services.yml` configuration.

You just have to write this :

```
// current controller

public function myAction() {
  $test = $this->get(SomeController::class)->someAction($param);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I don't even need that answer anymore but I hope it'll help someone else!

Comment: Seems to work for a function that doesn't use Entity Manager. I tried with another function which constructs a query with query builder and I have an error when I declare the Entity Manager `Error: Call to a member function has() on null`. But I still can access to the function.